# jQuery autocomplete data undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jquery v 2.0.0 and jquery ui 1.10.3

Following is my jquery ui autocomplete code:

```
$nameField.combobox({
            source: people,
            buttonSelector: '.toggleList',
            focus: function () {
                return false;
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $nameField.val(ui.item.name).data({
                    id: ui.item.id,
                    name: ui.item.name,
                    birthdate: ui.item.birthdate
                });
                return false;
            }
        }).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            if (!_.include(self.idArr, item.id)) {
                return $('<li></li>').data('ui-autocomplete-item', item).append('<a>' + item.name + '</a>').appendTo(ul);
            }
        };
```

This was working perfectly in older version of jquery. But after the upgrade, when I click the `.toggleList` button, it opens the first time and there's another button to add the selected name to a div. After that when I click the `.toggleList' combo selector, the autocomplete is not opening. It gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'data' of undefined jquery.ui.autocomplete.js?1376892069:527
```

Anyone came across any issues like this? I tried several fixes mentioned in other stackoverflow threads, but none of them are working for me.

Hope someone could help me to fix this bug

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue, you found a solution?

Comment: The people tell to try something like uiAutocomplete or autocomplete instead "ui-autocomplete", but so far I know, "ui-autocomplete" is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### I found the solution!

Somepeople think that "ui-autocomplete" is wrong, so them uses "autocomplete" or "uiAutocomplete", but that is wrong. Actually, "ui-autocomplete" is the right way to do this.

I have the same issue you have, and I find with a friend the problem of this code. Instead:

```
.data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            if (!_.include(self.idArr, item.id)) {
                return $('<li></li>').data('ui-autocomplete-item', item).append('<a>' + item.name + '</a>').appendTo(ul);
            }
        };
```

Use:

```
._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            if (!_.include(self.idArr, item.id)) {
                return $('<li></li>').data('ui-autocomplete-item', item).append('<a>' + item.name + '</a>').appendTo(ul);
            }
        };
```

I think combobox and autocomplete returns a data('ui-autocomplete'), so if you type .data('ui-autocomplete') you're doing something like:

```
.data('ui-autocomplete').data('ui-autocomplete')
```

What's wrong....well, actually I don't know why this don't work and why without this works, but trust me, delete .data('ui-autocomplete') and be happy!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. For some reason, it seems working :)

Comment: Hhahaha, yes, I don't know why this works, but is a relief know that works. :)