# What can be the causes of firefox not loading the javascript in an iframe

Tags: jquery, firefox, iframe, autocomplete

I have a problem I am finding very difficult to debug, it seems to only be occuring on firefox when firefox is loading my code from within an iframe. I do not know to much about browser differences and to make this work the problem is intermittent. I have tracked it down to this error in javascript which I do not get on chrome.

> TypeError: $(...).autocomplete(...).data(...) is null

Now the relevant code that I think is being called is from a javascript autocomplete feature like this.

```
$("#field").data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) { ... }
```

The thing that is confusing me is it seems to be an intermittant firefox bug, I haven't been able to reproduce it on chrome. Does anyone have any insight into what is going on here?

N.B. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18349929/jquery-autocomplete-data-undefined-error), [this](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8996) and several similar ones, but my problem is that the .data is returning null, not that `.data("autocomplete")` is `undefined`...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: oh and of course, just let me know if I can add any more detail, I'd be happy to.

Comment: post link to check the issue if possible.

Comment: What errors are you getting on console/Firebug?

Comment: `TypeError: $(...).autocomplete(...).data(...) is null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you provide some jsFiddle or a concrete example to work on? It's hard to say what the problem is.

Anyway maybe you can solve the problem with:

```
if( $("#field").data() ){
    var fieldAuto = $("#field").data( "ui-autocomplete" );
    if( fieldAuto ){
        fieldAuto._renderItem = function( ul, item ) { ... };
    }
}
```

The `ui-autocomplete` depends on the jQuery version, so it could be possible that you must change it

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point, I'll try your suggestion and try and get a jsfiddle up and running with a SSCE if that doesn't work (unfortunately it's a tightly coupled system that I inherited so it might take a while.)

Comment: If anyone is curious I managed to find out the cause of the problem. The javascript was being run on every page and would crash on pages that did not have the elements that were needed (causing the error). This was one solution, another solution was just changing the function to ensure that it would only run on the desired page.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of jquery ui you're using it will either be "autocomplete" or "ui-autocomplete".

```
var autoComplete = input.data("ui-autocomplete");
if(typeof(autoComplete) == "undefined")
    autoComplete = input.data("autocomplete");
 autoComplete._renderItem = function(ul, item) {....}
```

Please check and let me know, in case of any further issue.

Cheers.. :)